# Getting error while store data in sql server 2005 through textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, sql-server-2005

I am storing data (approx. 1500 words) in SQL server 2005 through textbox and button. I am using this code.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn.Open();
    String query = String.Format("insert into try (data,sno) values ('{0}',22)",TextBox1.Text);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Label1.Text = "submitted";
    conn.Close();
}
```

I have column `'data'` of data type `'char(4000)'`.

Problem is that, when I store 1st paragraph (approx 1500 words), it stored successfully. But when I stored another paragraph (approx 1500 words), it show me the error.

> "Incorrect syntax near 's'. Unclosed quotation mark after the
>   character string ',22)'."

What is the problem ??

Comment: one other item aside form the answers below, is that you may want to use a varchar instead of a char, given that char(4000) will always take 4 KB of space regardless of the content, while varchar(4000) will take up to 4 KB, entirely dependent on what you store.

Comment: i got it.... thanks to all of you..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)

```
String query = "insert into try (data,sno) values (@data,22)"; 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", TextBox1.text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In this way you don't need to worry about the presence of single quotes in your text and, the most important thing, you avoid [SqlInjection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Also, "try" is a keyword in SQL Server, so you would want to qualify it either with quotes (") or brackets ([]) -- "try" or [try]

Comment: @CodeMonkey1313 are you sure? I can't find it in the [following list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx). However I concur. It's not a good name choice

Comment: looks like I was about half-right -- they syntax is "BEGIN TRY", so the word "TRY" itself isn't a keyword, but part of a key phrase. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

Answer (score 2):

`String.Format` will not escape the input string suitably for use in an SQL statement, which will lead to errors & [serious vulnerabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

You should use [*Parameterized Queries*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) which are designed specifically to address this.

Answer (score 1):

Does your text contains `'` letter? If yes then it is breaking `INSERT` query.

If you would try to insert following text:

> Hello' there

Then your query would look like this:

```
insert into try (data,sno) values ('Hello' there,22)
```

Which results in incorrect query.

This is not the way queries should be done, because it leads to security issues (read more: [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)) you should use [parametrized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx).

Comment: I assume someone gave you a -1 as you asked a question instead of giving a solution.

Comment: Also with things like this its particularly important to carry on and explain the potential consequences

Comment: "Does your text contains ' letter? If yes then it is breaking INSERT query." = **rhetorical** question...

Comment: I found it useful that you showed what its actually doing in the query, thanks man

Comment: @Stephen sure thing, if you think that any of the provided answers is good, then consider accepting it

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you have an `'`, or multiple `'`s, in the `TextBox1.Text`.  You will need to replace all single quotes for double.

```
String query = String.Format("insert into try (data,sno) values ('{0}',22)",Replace(TextBox1.Text,"'","''"));
```

However, this approach will open you up to SQL Injection attacks.  I'd recommend using a Stored Procedure, like the following:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "spInsertDataIntoTry";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", TextBox.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Otherwise, you could use [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) like others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

"Incorrect syntax near 's' - this indicates your sql statements is wrong.
i guess that your input content maybe contains sql server keywords, so check your 2nd paragraph is there any keyword such as "'".
for example:
2nd paragraph is: how's the weather? it's cool!!!!!!!
so the sql statement is: insert into try (data,sno) values ('how's the weather? it's cool!!!!!!!',22) 
it will arise an exception incorrect syntax near 's'